# Several years experience or Several years'experience

Tags: possessives

Several years experience or Several years'experience. Is the possessive apostrophe needed?

Comment: The apostrophe is mandatory here.  However, it should be "several years' experience" with a space before the word "experience".  Omitting the space is worse than omitting than omitting the apostrophe.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the apostrophe is correct, as the experience **belongs to** the several years, though I’d imagine you’d very often see this phrase without it, and there’s a possibility that these days it would be accepted as being just as correct.

Comment: When there are [Hollywood blockbusters](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0313737/) not using the apostrophe, and nobody seems to care, I think we might be fighting a losing battle!